# How to set a maximum limit in WooCommerce orders per item & per user & per date

Tags: woocommerce

I need to limit user's orders in WooCommerce in a way that each user would be able to order some specific products for a limited amount per day. this way the limitation is "per user"/"per product"/"per day" !

for example each user could buy only 10 items of a product each day, and the next day he would be able to buy 10 more.

I have checked almost all plugins related to limiting orders but none of them had all these conditions. I also read some sample codes here like [this one](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/39234686/woocommerce-getting-completed-status-orders-by-user-in-a-period-of-time). but since I'm new to php and wordpress coding I couldn't figure out how to change it to my preference.

I appreciate any help

Comment: Sorry but your question is just too broad and real development.

Comment: @LoicTheAztec atleast point me in the right direction if possible. Isn't there a piece of code which I could edit and not write the whole thing from start ? Because I'm not sure where to begin.

Comment: I am sorry but you should better hire someone skilled in woocommerce dev for that… You can have a look to [Woocommerce top users list in StackOverFlow](https://stackoverflow.com/tags/woocommerce/topusers) or search in other places like [Woocommerce official developer list](https://woocommerce.com/experts/)…

Answer (score 1):

I would start with adding a function to the `woocommerce_add_to_cart` hook.This is a basically a hook that get called when a new product is added to the cart. Then I will work with the users meta where I will check if the user has bought this product already when this has happened. If there is no such data I will then add it to the users meta.

Mind that you have two scenarios here - first, the product is just added to the cart and not purchased, the second one is when the product is purchased. This is important  because you will have also the case when the user deletes product from the cart and you will need also a hook there so you can update the user meta. Here you can use `woocommerce_remove_cart_item` and `woocommerce_after_cart_item_quantity_update` (check for references [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/49148016/which-hook-to-alter-quantity-update-in-woocommerce-cart-page) )

And finally you will need to hook on order completion -> check [those](https://squelchdesign.com/web-design-newbury/woocommerce-detecting-order-complete-on-order-completion/) hooks.

But still, one of the most important parts is how you are going to build the array for the user meta. I would suggest creating an associative array with key value -> the product id. As value of the array you can have another array with date of purchase and products quantity. Something like this:

```
$users_products = [
  product_id1 => [ 
    'date' => timestamp,
    'quantity' => 3
  ],
  product_id2 => [ 
    'date' => timestamp,
    'quantity' => 3
  ]
];
```

Where `product_id1` and `product_id2` are actual products ids. This way it will be easier for you to loop through the user meta and check if the current product is in the list. Also to avoid making this user meta data too big check if the date of each item  is not outdated and if so - delete(unset) this element from the array and update it the user meta with the refreshed data.

There is much more that you will need to code but I think this will be a good start for you.